# jQuery autocomplete for json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am returning array of strings from controller to ajax call. trying to set to textbox those values. in textbox it is not populating. but I can see data in success method.

```
  [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public JsonResult GetWorkNamesAutoPoplate(string companyName)
    {
        ...
        var newKeys = companyNameslst.Select(x => new string[] { x }).ToArray();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newKeys);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JS

```
 $(document).on('change', '[name="FindCompanyName"]', function () {
     $('[name="FindCompanyName"]').autocomplete({        
        source: function (request, response) {           
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetWorkNamesAutoPoplate",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { companyName: $('[name="FindCompanyName"]').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));    
                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }    
    });
 });
```

`alert(JSON.stringify(data));` display like this.
[image]

How to populate this data in textbox

Comment: Have a look at this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578169/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-with-asp-net/27578198#27578198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of your json is **an array of arrays**, i think you should return it as **an array**

```
var newKeys = companyNameslst.ToArray();
```

also, your data are serialized twice,

one from line,

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newKeys);
```

and second time from `JsonResult` action filter

```
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

sending json data like,

```
return Json(newKeys, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newKeys);
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

should work.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may resolve your issue :

```
success: function (data) {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                  if (data != null) {
                    response(data.d);
                   }
                }
```

Also this link might help you to get some information :[How to use source: function()... and AJAX in JQuery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385892/how-to-use-source-function-and-ajax-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)